# Magento 2 admin dropdown multiselect no fields for options

Tags: magento2

I can not edit or add new attribute with dropdown or multiselect (I have no fields for options).
I try to clean cache, reindex, deploy files, but nothing
No errors on console
CSS and JS was Merged! I try and set to No and again is the same.

Magento version 2.2.2 - latest release
php 7.0
mysql mariadb

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you want achieve so accordingly , i can try to help?

Comment: Between Attribute properties and advanced attribute properties for Dropdown and Multiselect should have Manage Swatch (Values of Your Attribute) and options for fill new dropdown or multiselect values. In my case I have not this Manage Swatch (Values of Your Attribute) and can not fill my option values.

Answer (score 0):

Click on **save and edit** button then you will get option to fill options.

[image]

Comment: this not help me

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the same... no fields for option values
 [image]